# When would giving an example of these functions be impossible?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

I'm trying to understand exactly what would make a request like this impossible

A function defined on $[-1, 1]$ with $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-\ }f(x) = \infty$

A continuous function defined on $[-1, 1]$ such that $f(1/n) = n$ for every positive integer $n$

Comment: If the limit as $x$ goes to $0$ is infinite, the function cannot be continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "when" ? There is nothing variable in these questions !

Answer (score 2):

Such a request is not impossible. Indeed, consider $f: [-1, 1] \to \Bbb R$ defined by $$f(x) := \begin{cases} |x|^{-1} & x \neq 0, \\ 0 & x = 0.\end{cases}$$

This also satisfies $f(1/n) = n$ for all positive integers $n$. This is not continuous at $0$, by the way. You didn't demand continuity at the beginning.

---

However, what you wrote does **not** suffice. You cannot just say consider a continuous function with that property because you have to show that such a function exists.
In fact, if you do impose continuity, then no such real-valued function exists because continuity would enforce $$f(0) = \lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x) = \infty \notin \Bbb R.$$